# Reduce array of objects to x number of items. Trying to keep at least 2 of specific object property value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects which, if larger than 8 items, I want to reduce to 8 items.

The array can look like this:

```
[{
    id: 0,
    type: 'product',
    name: 'Product 1'
},{
    id: 0,
    type: 'product',
    name: 'Product 2'
},{
    id: 0,
    type: 'product',
    name: 'Product 3'
},{
    id: 0,
    type: 'accessory',
    name: 'Accessory 1'
},{
    id: 0,
    type: 'accessory',
    name: 'Accessory 2'
},{
    id: 0,
    type: 'accessory',
    name: 'Accessory 3'
},{
    id: 0,
    type: 'accessory',
    name: 'Accessory 4'
},{
    id: 0,
    type: 'accessory',
    name: 'Accessory 5'
},{
    id: 0,
    type: 'document',
    name: 'Document 1'
},{
    id: 0,
    type: 'article',
    name: 'Article 1'
},{
    id: 0,
    type: 'article',
    name: 'Article 2'
},{
    id: 0,
    type: 'article',
    name: 'Article 3'
}]
```

The **types** available are fixed, however it doesn't always have to contain all types.

What I want is to reduce it in a way that it will try to maintain at least 2 of each object property **type**.

So shrink array to 8, and try to keep at least 2 of each type or fill by whatever space is left.

For instance, in the example, if the array was reduced to 8 with above criteria it would mean it is left with 2 products, 3 accessories (as accessories has the highest number of items to fill it to 8), 1 document and 2 articles.

Logically I would look at this by looping through the array, removing items until it has a length of 8 by basically removing 1 of each type that has the highest length at the time until that type reaches a length of 2.

I'm a bit stumped on how to achieve this however, and there must be an efficient way to go about this.

Comment: Add a proper question, So, everyone can understand easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's my attempt at solving your issue/request, explanations in the code.

```
let totalCount = array.length;
let typeCounts = {};

// Separate the array by type and move to an object for easier access
// Result: { product: [{id:0,type:'product',name:'Product 1'},{id:0,type:'product',name:'Product 2'},{id:0,type:'product',name:'Product 3'}], accessory: [ ... ], ... }
array.map((elem) => typeCounts[elem.type] = [...(typeCounts[elem.type] ? typeCounts[elem.type] : []), elem]);

// Keep reducing the amount of array entries by one per type per loop
while(totalCount > 8) {
    let unchanged = true;

    for (let type in typeCounts) {
        if (typeCounts[type].length > 2) {
            typeCounts[type].pop(); // Remove the last entry of that type
            totalCount -= 1;
            unchanged = false;
        }
    }

    // Should it not be possible to reduce the array to 8 items, break
    // Example: Using an array with 9 types, 1 entry per type
    // Ensures we don't get stuck in an infinite loop
    if (unchanged) {
        break;
    }
}

// Join our entries back together
// Result: [{"id":0,"type":"product","name":"Product 1"},{"id":0,"type":"product","name":"Product 2"},{"id":0,"type":"accessory","name":"Accessory 1"},{"id":0,"type":"accessory","name":"Accessory 2"},{"id":0,"type":"accessory","name":"Accessory 3"},{"id":0,"type":"document","name":"Document 1"},{"id":0,"type":"article","name":"Article 1"},{"id":0,"type":"article","name":"Article 2"}]
let reducedArray = Object.values(typeCounts).reduce((acc, value) => acc.concat(value), []);
```

Comment: Tested a number of arrays now and this actually works perfectly and does exactly what I needed. I'll do some adjustments to have it also work in IE11, but that shouldn't be an issue. Thank you very much, also for the added explanation!